# How to use _renderitem method with jQuery Tagit plugin

Tags: tag-it

I am trying to use jQuery Auto-complete _renderitem method with jQuery tagit plugin .

Can someone help me with it?

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a correct answer, but still it can help saving hours of work : Use selectize instead, it is way more simpler and up-to-date http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/